# .minecraft folder cannot be on a mounted volume - why not, and can anyone suggest a workaround?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, pc

My dad likes to mount a partition of the RAID array (read: a lot of hard drives made to look like one massive hard drive to Windows) as C:\home using the `mountvol` command in Command Prompt (it does NOT have a drive letter - it is mounted at C:\home).  I recently moved my game folder in there and now minecraft will not let me select it as the game directory.  If I make it C:\ or anywhere else on the C:\ drive or any other volume with a drive letter, it works fine.  But if I make it any subfolder of C:\home, minecraft pukes.  It finds the folder okay, and lets me save the profile, but when I exit the settings and go back in I find it has blanked out the Game directory field and if I try to launch the game, errors out.

Can anybody suggest a workaround, or tell me why the heck this is happening?  I know why it's failing - it's trying to get the volume UUID or similar of the drive (C:), which does not match the volume UUID of the mounted volume (C:\Home), so it pukes.  My question is: why the heck does it need to do that?

Comment: Uh, finally another interesting Minecraft question. Have you tried assigning a drive letter to it?

Answer (score 3):

A suggested work around, you could try [symlinks on windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/) this might bypass the games detection and just assume it's another local drive.